# Store jwt claims in cookies using owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, owin, jwt

I have some web sites in asp.net webforms and classic asp. I receive request from an api gateway witch handles login and includes a jwt token in the header.

On my web sites, i'm using Owin with JWTBearerAuthentication to validate the jwt token and reject bad request.
This work very well.

Now, if the jwt is valid, I have to calculate additional custom claims (like roles taken from a db) and store them in a cookie so that I don't have to do it on each request.

Of course, I need to access these claims in asp.net webforms and classic asp sites.

Here is the startup class, with token validation method

```
  [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebForms.Startup))]
  namespace WebForms
  {
      public class Startup
      {
          public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
          {
              ConfigureTokenConsumption(app);
          }

          private void ConfigureTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
          {
              //Read parameters in config file
              string issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:Issuer"];
              string audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:Audience"];

              string certificat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Certificat"];
              X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
              byte[] raw = GetBytes(certificat);
              cert.Import(raw);

              X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
              store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

              //prepare token validation options
              var options = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active };
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                  ValidAudiences = new[] { audience },
                  ValidIssuer = issuer,
                  IssuerSigningToken = new X509SecurityToken(cert),
                  RequireExpirationTime = true,
                  ValidateAudience = true,
                  ValidateLifetime = false,
                  ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0)
              };

              //Add in owin pipeline
              app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
          }

          /// <summary>
          /// string to bytes conversion
          /// </summary>
          /// <param name="str"></param>
          private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
          {
              byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
              Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
              return bytes;
          }
      }
  }
```

Basically, when the jwt is valid, I have to get custom claims, and add them in a cookie, except if a cookie is still available. Then I would like to find all claims later in my site in a principal or identity.

I searched the web and found samples where cookie creation is done in a login page. As the login process is not handled by me, I don't have a login page. I think I have to insert that in the pipeline, but how ?

I found things like UseExternalSignInCookie and UseCookieAuthentication, what is it for ? Which one should I use ? Can I hook custom code?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve the problem?